# Getting All Possibilities - Schoolwork

Tags: java, arrays

What I need to do is take a String array with each element having an exact length of 2, and find all possible combinations of the the elements, using each character within each String. By that I mean the String array {"Ss", "Ff"} returns "SF", "Sf", "sF", "sf". I have already tried a loop method that counts the iteration and then chooses a letter based on that, but it only works for arrays with a single element:

```
    public String [] generatePossibilities(String [] s)
{
    if(s[0].length() != 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    String [] r = new String [s.length * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
    {
        r[i] = getPossibility(i, s);
    }

    return r;
}

private String getPossibility(int iteration, String [] source)
{
    int [] choose = new int [source.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < choose.length; i++)
    {
        choose[i] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = choose.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(iteration < 1)
            break;

        choose[i] = 1;
        iteration--;
    }

    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
        result += source[i].substring(choose[i], choose[i] + 1);

    return result;
}
```

**Solved** Thanks Sven!

```
    public String [] generatePossibilities(String [] s)
{
    if(s[0].length() != 2)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    ArrayList<String> ra = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {           
        for(int j = 0; j < s[i].length(); j++)
        {
            String c = s[i].substring(j, j + 1);

            if(ra.size() < 2)
            {
                ra.add(c);
            }

            else
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < ra.size(); k++)
                {
                    String s1 = ra.get(k);
                    if(s1.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase(c))
                        continue;
                    else
                    {
                        s1 = c + s1;
                        ra.add(s1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < ra.size(); j++)
        {
            if(ra.get(j).length() != s.length - i)
            {
                ra.remove(j);
                j--;
            }
        }
    }

    String [] r = new String [ra.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++)
    {
        r[i] = ra.get(i);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: can you give some more example. does the source array contains only 2 string or it can me more also ?

Comment: @ashok_p It can contain an unlimited amount of Strings, but each String has only 2 characters. Another example is {"SS", "Ff", "dd"} which should result in another String array which has the length of 2 * the source array's length (all combinations) with the Strings {"SFd", "SFd", "Sfd", "Sfd", ...).

Comment: +1 for trying yourself and showing some code

Comment: Downvoted twice? Why did I deserve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate the array of character tuples from last element to first. In each step you append to each current character the possibilities of the last iteration. You therefore double the elements in each step. 
So for your example in the first iteration you have {Ff} and this would result to the two strings "F" and "f". In the next step you take each character of {Ss} and append each string of the last step to it getting "SF", "Sf", "sF" and "sf". You could then continue with further character tuples.